# sql averaging rows on same resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to accomplish something kind of weird, i have a table that has the flowing select output on a select * (I'm just putting 4 rows to simplify). 
each pair of rows on the table is information from ~ the same time, i want to have some kind of average made from each "event" and output it into the result.

Current Result Set

```
VehicleId                               ActivityDateTime          SensorValue   SensorPilot
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:52:54.010   750           0
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:52:54.007   770           1
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:51:54.010   800           0
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:51:54.007   900           1
```

and i want to achieve having a query that will get me that resultset and at the same time have an average of each "event" something like this.

```
VehicleId                               ActivityDateTime          SensorValue   SensorPilot
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:52:54.010   750           0
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:52:54.007   770           1
**66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE  2017-02-17 17:52:54.008   760           2**
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:51:54.010   800           0
66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE    2017-02-17 17:51:54.007   900           1
**66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE  2017-02-17 17:51:54.008   850           2**
```

Is something like this possible? or should i try and approach this son another way?

Im trying to do a view out of this query if for some reason that is relevant

Comment: You could put the data in a temp table. Query that temp table 2 times, 1 for regular data, and 1 for summed version... then union them.

Comment: @manderson and how can i achieve so the average groups the closest rows together? meaning in my quesiton on the first table how do i make row 1 avg with row 2 and not row 2 with row 3

Comment: ah my bad, I thought VehicleId was unique.

Comment: How do you know when an `event` begins and ends? is it merely by pairs of consecutive dates?

Comment: What are you averaging?  What does the ** mean in the result set?

Comment: @JoshPart yes, just by the date, you can see how they are .003 seconds apart, so some kind of goruping all dates .005 apart could do it, just that i don't know how to do that

Comment: @WesH the * are just for you to see the added rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (Row_Number - 1)/ 2 to generate the consecutive pairing.  Then union the base set with the aggregated set.

```
Use TEMPDB;
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..test') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
    GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (
                        VehicleID VARCHAR(38),
                        ActivityDateTime DATETIME2(7),
                        SensorValue INT,
                        SensorPilot INT
                      );
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
VALUES ('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE', '2017-02-17 17:52:54.010', 750, 0),
('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE', '2017-02-17 17:52:54.007', 770, 1),
('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE', '2017-02-17 17:51:54.010', 800, 0),
('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE', '2017-02-17 17:51:54.007', 900, 1);

WITH cte
AS (SELECT  *,
            ConsecutivePairs = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.VehicleID ORDER BY t.ActivityDateTime) - 1) / 2
    FROM    dbo.Test AS t
   )
SELECT  cte.VehicleID,
        cte.ActivityDateTime,
        cte.SensorValue,
        cte.SensorPilot,
        cte.ConsecutivePairs
FROM    cte
UNION ALL
SELECT  cte.VehicleID,
        ActivityDateTime = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, MIN(cte.ActivityDateTime), MAX(cte.ActivityDateTime)) / 2, MIN(cte.ActivityDateTime)),
        SensorValue = AVG(cte.SensorValue),
        SensorPilot = COUNT(cte.VehicleID),
        cte.ConsecutivePairs
FROM    cte
GROUP BY cte.VehicleID,
         cte.ConsecutivePairs
ORDER BY cte.ConsecutivePairs, cte.SensorPilot       ;
```

Comment: your example works very good,, and no extra temp tables needed which is good, im trying to put it on my actual DB and i get `The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.`

Comment: You're wanting to see the average timestamp, but it is at the millisecond grain.  If you have a larger gap, you'll overflow the integer value.  Change microsecond to millisecond.  It that is still a problem, change it to second.

Comment: @pato.llaguno.  I've updated the query to use millisecond.

Comment: @pato.llaguno also, if you have a large number or rows, an index ordered by vehicleID, then activitydatetime, including the rest of the columns in the select, will help it run faster.

Comment: thanks @Wes H 2 questions, what would happen if for some reason a vehicleID doesn't have 2 readings per event? my desired output would be that it would only pass through as the average, so basically if there is no row to average it with copy the row and only changing the pilot sensor to 2. And secondly, where should i put a where clause to filter by VehicleID and a datetime range? thanks a lot, you are pretty good at this

Comment: Your sample data doesn't really define an event.  if that is another column, you'll need to add it to the partition by statement.  That would affect the final row because it is using a Count rather than a static value.

Comment: As far as filter, add the where clause to the CTE statement
From dbo.Test
Where vehicleID = variable for VehicleID
AND (ActivityDateTime >= variable for StartTime 
and ActivityDateTime < variable for EndTime)

Comment: I think i could add a EventID column in the insert since it is done in a trigger, this could help simplify this a lot right? should i still need the partition? im not sure i understand what that does, what would i need to modify if i had a column with type uniqueidentifier that groups the events together?

Comment: partition makes individual buckets of data just like group by.  in this example it is used to reset the row_number so it starts at 1 for each vehicle id.  If you add EventID, you'll want it in the partition statement so the row_number is reset for each vehicle event (VehicleID & EventID)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a lot of time, but this will get you started... You'll have to do something about the dates.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( vehicleid VARCHAR(100), activitydate DATETIME, sensorvalue INT, sensorpilot INT)


INSERT INTO #temptable (vehicleid, activitydate, sensorvalue, sensorpilot)
VALUES ('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE',    '2017-02-17 17:52:54.010',   750,           0)
INSERT INTO #temptable (vehicleid, activitydate, sensorvalue, sensorpilot)
VALUES ('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE',    '2017-02-17 17:52:54.007',   770,           1)
INSERT INTO #temptable (vehicleid, activitydate, sensorvalue, sensorpilot)
VALUES ('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE',    '2017-02-17 17:51:54.010',   800,           0)
INSERT INTO #temptable (vehicleid, activitydate, sensorvalue, sensorpilot)
VALUES ('66B828BE-6EB9-4B69-AB5C-125439F065DE',    '2017-02-17 17:51:54.007',   900,           1)


SELECT NTILE(2) OVER(ORDER BY vehicleid DESC) AS RankVehicle
        , vehicleid
        , activitydate
        , sensorvalue
        , sensorpilot
FROM #temptable


UNION ALL 


SELECT A.RankVehicle, A.vehicleid, '' AS ActivityDate, AVG(A.SensorValue) AS SensorValue, 2 AS SensorPilot
FROM ( 
        SELECT NTILE(2) OVER(ORDER BY vehicleid DESC) AS RankVehicle
                , vehicleid
                , activitydate
                , AVG(sensorvalue) AS SensorValue
                , sensorpilot
        FROM #temptable
    GROUP BY vehicleid, activitydate, sensorpilot
    ) A
GROUP BY A.RankVehicle, A.vehicleid





DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: Thanks, ill look into your example, what is the RankVehicle for?

Comment: also, shouldn't the OVER() be orderby activitydate instead?